# Выход в интернет по локальной сети через один из компьютеров

Tags: сеть, windows

Вот смотрите, у меня на comp1 есть 2 сетевые карты: одна к выходу в интернет, а другая для соединения с другим компьютером, то есть comp2. Как сделать, чтобы пользователь comp2 по локальной сети мог пользоваться интернетом компьютера comp1. Ещё раз повторяю, что comp1 и comp2 соединены по локальной сети

Comment: Уточните операционную систему)

Comment: WindowsXP на comp1 на comp2 ось win7

Answer (score 2):

Например у нас на comp1 2 IP адреса
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx это наш внешний IP адрес
192.168.0.1 это IP нашей внутреней локалки

Тогда на comp2 ставим 
Ip 192.168.0.2 
основной шлюз 192.168.0.1 
DNS 192.168.0.1

После этого на comp1 заходим в Свойства подключения к интернету, там нужно найти галочку "Разрешить общий доступ".

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как у всех, но лично в моей windows 7 потребовалось отключение некоторых "политик" (я был носителем модема с доступом в интернет) и установка программы CCPROXY. Кстати, с помощью её можно мониторить доступ второго компьютера. А как соединиться, выше, правильно описано было.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу про общий доступ я когда-то пользовался в схожей ситуации программой [handycache](http://handycache.ru/) , она ещё кучу всего умела помимо простого проброса соединения

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте сетевой мост, и разрешите в соединении (на котором висит инет) общее подключение. настраивать ip и dns не обязательно, но с ними соединение при включении ПК будет происходить быстрей.